# Java: compile conflict: return type is incompatible with HATEOAS ResourceSupport.getId

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, spring-hateoas

So I have this HATEOAS entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User extends ResourceSupport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    public User() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
    return new Long(id);
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id.longValue();
    }
}
```

My entity has an id of type long, but HATEOAS's ResourceSupport requires that getId return a Link.

The entity has a Long id because the db has a long id, and it is a persisted entity.  How can I implement this entity with HATEOAS?

Comment: I'm just starting to play around with Spring HATEOAS myself, but my understanding is that the `ResourceSupport` is supposed to be a DTO rather than a live entity.

Comment: Oh.  That would make sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the "Link Builder" section of the documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#fundamentals.obtaining-links.builder

There, it describes how to use a `ControllerLinkBuilder` to create the `Link` using a separate controller class. Your `User` Object would implement `Identifiable<Long>`, as the example in the page above shows.

Comment: Yeah but I need to extend ResourceSupport to get the .add(Link) method

Comment: The javadoc for `ResourceSupport` says "Base class for DTOs to collect links." So, @chrylis' comment above seems to be correct. Your entity shouldn't be your `ResourceSupport` implementation. That would be messy anyway -- you would end up having the "links" `ArrayList` in `ResourceSupport` in your database.

Comment: Yeah that was precisely my confusion.  I got it now, I had totally missed the DTO part in the reading.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can create one BeanResource bean which extends ResourceSupport bean like.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "id" })
public class BeanResource extends ResourceSupport {

 @JsonUnwrapped
 private Object resorce;

 public Resource(Object resorce) {
    this.resorce = resorce;
 }

 public Object getResorce() {
    return resorce;
 }

}
```

just Unwrap resource instance property so that BeanResource bean will render json like user bean along with ResourceSupport bean will render link json object,

after that you can create assembler like this.

```
public class UserAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<User, BeanResource> {

public UserAssembler() {
    super(User.class, BeanResource.class);
}

@Override
public Resource toResource(User user) {
    Resource userResource = new Resource(user);
    try {
        Link selfLink = linkTo(
                methodOn(UserController.class).getUser(user.getId()))
                .withSelfRel();
        userResource.add(selfLink);

    } catch (EntityDoseNotExistException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userResource;
}

}
```

and in controller just attach Resource bean which contains user bean like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getUser(@PathVariable String userId)
        throws EntityDoseNotExistException {
    User user = userService.getUser(userId);
    Resource userResource = userAssembler.toResource(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<Resource>(userResource, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: In line 7 of first block you are tryng to make a constructor? A set property? Or a general method?

Comment: linkTo and methodOn are static method, please check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilder.html